# SWITCHMAP operator throws error when used with ParamMap

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables, switchmap

I'm trying to get data by special types.

So I use 2 observables.

```
  this.activatedRoute.paramMap
    .pipe(
      takeWhile(() => this.alive),
      switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.setProductStatus(params.get('status'))
      )
    );

setProductStatus(status: any): void {
  this.isLoading= true;

  switch (status) {
  case 'listing':
    //some logic here;
    break;
  case 'purchased':
    //logic here;
    break;
  case 'in-review':
    //logic here
    break;
  default:
    this.route.navigate(['/path/relativePage']);
    break;

  }

  this.productService.getProductByStatus(status)

    .subscribe(data => {
        this.isLoading= false;
        this.products = data
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error)
      });
```

As you can see, I've tried to use a switchMap operator but it throws an error:

> Argument of type '(params: ParamMap) => void' is not assignable to
> parameter of type '(value: ParamMap, index: number) =>
> ObservableInput'.   Type 'void' is not assignable to type
> 'ObservableInput'.

I've found a similar example on

https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/switching-to-most-recent-observable-switchmap

Comment: `switchMap` must return observable.  So your `setProductStatus` must return observable.

Comment: you can use in your setProductStatus function, `return of(your value)`. Or **better** use [map](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map) to transform a response in another one:`this.activatedRoute.paramMap .pipe(takeWhile(() => this.alive), map((params: ParamMap) => this.setProductStatus(params.get('status'))`. NOTE: don't forget subscribe (or use pipe async) to "execute" the Observable

Comment: The error message is quire precise in this case. Do you understand what it means? If not you should spend some time to understand what it means and learn how the compiler communicates. In this case it says, you passed a function that returns `void`, where it expected a function that returns a value of type `ObservableInput` (which could be a simple `Observable`).

Answer (score -1):

You need to import the switchMapoperator to use it. Add the following line at the top of your file, where you have your other imports:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
```

Comment: It's already imported

Comment: If the function would not be importet, how would the compiler be able to complain about a wrong function argument?

Comment: @kavinda,  be careful, it's: `import {switchMap} from 'rxjs/operators'`